# Incorrect Syntax Near '+' - SQL/TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Trying to do this (in SQL Server Management Studio)

```
DECLARE @fun as int
SET @fun = 40
PRINT 'String' + 'Hello!'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_senddbmail
    @profile_name = 'Some working profile',
    @recipients = 'someone@example.ca',
    @subject =  'String' + 'Hello!',
    @body = 'Test email sendout'
```

Getting this error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Notice the first concatenation works, second doesn't.

The steps I've taken:

Retyped it all out (so its not a copy paste error). Tried changing it to ('String' + 'Hello!') and get error `Incorrect syntax near '('.` So I'm feeling a bit lost.

**EDIT 2:** I've changed the example because the same error happens when its two strings, no casts involved

Comment: first concatenation also gives error, you need to explcitly cast the integer to varchar

Comment: Not true, see edit above.

Comment: here convertion is happening from varchar to int,i tried it on sql 2012 server and get an error.

Comment: @radar you were right that the first one gives an error, but resolving it didn't solve the problem - sorry about that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Values passed to stored procedures parameters (in T-SQL) must be, umm, "single values" (can't think of the technical term just now). You cannot use code like:

```
@subject = A + B + C
```

you can only have code like

```
@subject = A
```

So in this case, you'd need something like:

```
DECLARE
  @fun      int
 ,@Subject  nvarchar(255)

SET @fun = 40

SET @Subject = 'String' + 'Hello!'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  --  Added the second underscore...
    @profile_name = 'Some working profile',
    @recipients = 'someone@example.ca',
    @subject = @Subject,
    @body = 'Test email sendout'
```

Comment: The term is expression, and you are right, thank you! I had just figured it out and was just coming back to write it but you beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 5):

try this, convert int value as varchar then concat with another varchar value

```
DECLARE @fun as int
SET @fun = 40
PRINT convert(varchar(10), @fun) + 'Hello!'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_senddbmail
@profile_name = 'Some working profile',
@recipients = 'someone@example.ca',
@subject =  convert(varchar(10), @fun) + 'Hello!',
@body = 'Test email sendout'
```

Comment: Both same answer, but the issue I'm having is that it is the concat that is giving me issues - not the cast (or lack of) read comment above.

Comment: what exatly error you get? and in your question, you talking about wraping in brackets , where?

Comment: your this line PRINT @fun + 'Hello!' gives then error

Comment: I changed the question because everyone was fixating on the casting (which was not the heart of the issue). I get the same error with the code above it, seems to be more obscure of an issue.